# Ways to resolve library conflict in JMeter?

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter, classloader, jsr223

Got a custom JSR223 Groovy sampler that communicates with API of one pretty specific application.
The one is from financial world, so it is as stealth as it can be, with barely anything like docs/howtos/resources/any-other-kind-of-clues at open/community sources.

The API proxy lib, as it turns out, is dependent on exactly particular versions of Apache HttpClient/HttpCore, and these are pretty old ones.

While JMeter itself *(I'm on version 4, that's our org policy)* is using the **newer** versions of both libs - and the aforementioned API classes have failed with these versions & get completely non-functional.

Since the HTTP libraries are already in the JMeter classpath at startup, simply drop older ones into the /lib folder alongside newer ones *(and use @grab afterwards - workaround that went well with standalone Groovy env)* doesn't work out, as it creates a conflict for JMeter  itself, and it failed to start properly.

Repacking the API classes into one big fat jar with all it's dependencies & than dropping it into /lib didn't help either.

Any clues on possible ways to solve that?

Is there any way to dynamically add these dependencies to the JSR223 run-time while excluding them from the JMeter's classpath?

Comment: You might have to relocate the deps e.g. with something like shadow

Comment: @cfrick, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

No, JMeter JSR223 uses same classes as JMeter application,

I opened a JMeter enhancement  [Add JSR223 support to given specific jars](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63538), that you can [vote](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/page.cgi?id=voting/user.html&bug_id=63538#vote_63538)

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your swift & constructive reaction.